# How to keep override standard New/Edit Button After the Production Deployment

Tags: salesforcedx, button-overrides, page-override

I have override standard New/Edit Button of the Custom Object.As the Production Deployment happens override standard New/Edit Button will change to Standard New/Edit Button,For every Production deployment Happens , I need to Manually override standard New/Edit Button. Is there any solution to keep override standard New/Edit Button After the Production Deployment

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your deployment process.

**If you are deploying from repository**

You need to retrieve this change to your local package definition from where you are deploying. This change is located under the `.object` metadata.

```xml
<actionName>Clone</actionName>
    <content>FundRequestCustomCloneButton</content>
    <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
    <type>Visualforce</type>
</actionOverrides>
```

For more detail see the documentation of [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) and [ActionOverride](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/actionoverride.htm#actionoverride).

**If you are deploying from sandbox via change set**

You need to move this change from production down to the sandbox or refresh the sandbox entirely.